# Scrapy: crawling finishes earlier than expected

Tags: python, scrapy

My crawler terminates earlier than expected, crawling only to the **fifth** level. Note I have not changed the default settings.

It does however say that there was a duplicate request. Is that the reason?

Here's the **output**:

```
2014-01-16 14:06:34+0800 [Squarefoot] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.abc.com/search/?districts%5B%5D=95&districts%5B%5D=97&from=121&from=91&perpage=30&size_max=700&size_min=500&sort=pa&type=rent> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_CLASS)
2014-01-16 14:06:34+0800 [Squarefoot] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: Can you put more details on what you're trying to do/what is your spider code? By default scrapy tries to avoid doing the same job twice: if you yield a request with the exact same parameters as one you already yielded it will ignore it.

Comment: thanks Robin for the response.

After many hours of debugging, I realised the problem had to do with the default canonicalize setting. Once I turned that off, it worked fine.